# HTML: Posicionar botón en pantalla

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría saber si es posible y como realizar la siguiente implementación:

En mi pagina web tengo una imagen de un coche en 2D como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo era añadir botones encima de la imagen como por ejemplo uno en la puerta y otro en la rueda delantera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar los botones, cada uno debería realizar una acción. Desconozco si los botones se pueden situar a mi gusto en una pagina web. Me gustaría no tener que utilizar coordenadas ya que, entiendo que dependiendo de la pantalla en la que se visualice, se verá distinto.

En caso de no ser posible mediante HTML o CSS como podría conseguir situar los botones?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Puedes usar un image-map responsive, con SVG es fácíl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo sin realizar demasiados cálculos, en css puedes usar tamaños basados en porcentajes, sin embargo también puedes usar tamaños basados en el tamaño de pantalla, vw y alto de la pantalla vh basado en eso puedes crear botones que cambien de forma dinámica, puede que haya tamaños donde si debas cambiar algunas proporciones, pero seria mas facil que hacerlo en px, aqui un ejemplo:

```css
.cart {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; /* Para evitar que los botones se salgan del contenedor*/
}
.cart img {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn_1,
.btn_2 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #C0392B;
  padding: 3vh 4vw; /* Usamos tamaños en vw y vh */
  font-size: 2vw; /* Usamos tamaños en vw */
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.btn_1 {
  position: absolute; /* Posicionamos de forma absoluta*/
  top: 54.5%; /* Calculamos la posición*/
  right: 37.5%; /* Calculamos la posición*/
}
.btn_2 {
  position: absolute; /* Posicionamos de forma absoluta*/
  right: 3.5%; /* Calculamos la posición*/
  bottom: 13%; /* Calculamos la posición*/
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rqf3.png">
  <span class="btn_1">Boton 1</span>
  <span class="btn_2">Boton 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es usar Responsive Web Design y así los botones estarán en la misma posicion sin importar el tamaño del dispositivo.

te pongo un ejemplo para posicionar un elemento puedes usar la propiedad position con cualquiera de sus valores fixed, absolute, etc.

Mejor aún es conseguir el mismo posicionamiento usando los margin con porcentajes el primer boton será casí: margin-left:65%; margin-top:75%;